# Reference Request: Estimates for Euler Lagrange PDE

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I am currently working on an applied problem where I need estimates for the solution of an Euler-Lagrange equation for a functional
$$I(u)=\int L dp $$
In N-dimensional euclidean space. I have looked through Evan's book but didn't  find what I need.

I am most interested  in $L^2/H^2/L^\infty$ estimates which depend at least partially on the data/form of L.

I realize this question  is quite broad so really I'll appreciate any pointers.

Kindly 
Afc